# Why iOS devices running BLE GATT Service in peripheral mode are not discovered in Windows (and Windows RT) 8 & 8.1

Tags: ios, windows-8, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have used the Heart Rate Monitor sample application C# and modified it to look for my custom profile that the iPhone is advertising. I double checked if the iPhone Peripheral is working using a Mac configured as central and android device also as central. The android device is not connecting to it because of an issue in andoid api but it can see the service.

I paired successfully the two devices (iOS and Windows, iOS and WindowsRT) and they are connected. I also restarted the Bluetooth on the both devices and reconnected them multiple times before debugging.

The windows 8 Heart Rate Monitor sample and the windows 8.1 Heart Rate Monitor sample doesn't discover the iPhone device service with the given uuid. I also tried to leave the UUID to the default one and mimic the Heart rate peripheral using iOS but with same outcome.

I even tried to connect to every BLENUM device that findAllAsync() discovers and none of them provide  the configured custom service.

Multiple solution proposals are welcome, the support for Windows BLE is next to nothing.

Comment: UPDATE: Keep the advertised data shorter than 26bytes (36 including the name), otherwise it will not show in the findAllAsync() result.

Answer (score 0):

After working on BLE for a while i found out this:

Keep the advertised data shorter than 26bytes (36 including the name), otherwise it will not show in the findAllAsync() result.

Comment: Could you share some of your code for the iOS device?  What exact versions of iOS and Windows are you using? My device (Using a CBPeripheralManager) will not pair with Windows 8.1.  The name shows up when Windows is scanning for devices, but does not pair correctly.

Comment: This is a problem (I suppose) with the BT Adapter drivers, some chipsets have problems with Windows 8.1 and are manifested like that. It is not related with the iOS dev. 2 of three different windows machines have the problem with the driver on Windows 8.1